# How to install and download FF in code view? For Mac on Pycharm

Tags: python, macos, mozilla

Sorry for pretty stupid question, but I am noob in python.

I got the task to write code that installs and downloads Mozilla Firefox. I code on Mac.

For now I wrote the following:

```
import os
import urllib
import time


def download():
    urllib.urlretrieve('https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win&lang=en-US',
                               r'/Users/user/Downloads/Firefox 74.0.dmg')


def install():
    os.system("cd /Users/user/Downloads/")
    time.sleep(15)
    os.system("hdiutil mount Firefox\ 74.0.dmg")
    time.sleep(15)
    os.system("open /Volumes/Firefox/")
    time.sleep(15)


def main():
    download()
    install()


main()
```

But that's it. I received a lot of pop-up windows and I don't know how to move forward.

Maybe, someone know how execute it?

Comment: It looks like that link is the Windows version of Firefox.

Comment: .dmg only for Mac. no?

Comment: It would appear that the download is a Windows executable, even though this command renames it to a .dmg file.